# What does rvm's making gemset pristine mean?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I can't find any thing about it on Google, or the rvm website.

When I run `rvm gemset copy 1.9.3-p194 1.9.3-p125-falcon`

```
=> Copying gemset from 1.9.3-p194 to 1.9.3-p125-falcon
=> Making gemset for 1.9.3-p125-falcon pristine.
```

is the output. what does this mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RVM runs `gem pristine` on the gem, which restores the gem to a pristine state.  The command `gem help pristine` from the command line offers more information about the underlying command.

> The pristine command compares an installed gem with the contents of its cached .gem file and restores any files that don't match the cached .gem's copy. If you have made modifications to an installed gem, the pristine command will revert them. All extensions are rebuilt and all bin stubs for the gem are regenerated after checking for modifications. If the cached gem cannot be found it will be downloaded.

Comment: "The pristine command compares an installed gem with the contents of its cached .gem file and restores any files that don't match the cached .gem's copy. If you have made modifications to an installed gem, the pristine command will revert them. All extensions are rebuilt and all bin stubs for the gem are regenerated after checking for modifications. If the cached gem cannot be found it will be downloaded." - from `gem help pristine`